# Pauli's first paper about the spin

Tags: quantum-spin, history, specific-reference, pauli-exclusion-principle

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#History) states, that the spin degree of freedom was first formulated by Pauli in 1924:

> In 1924 Wolfgang Pauli introduced what he called a "two-valued quantum degree of freedom" associated with the electron in the outermost shell.

However, there is no reference to this quote. Does someone know the publication where Pauli introduced this quantum number for the first time? The only paper I know [this one](http://www.springerlink.com/index/20W1M0VR050J033R.pdf), where he formulates his exclusion principle. But this is from 1925, so one year later.

Comment: There is a history-of-physics StackExchange.

Comment: Oh thanks. Ok, so I think this question can be closed then.

Comment: @thyme It can be migrated, but I think a mod has to do that.

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pauli himself talked about this in his Nobel Lecture: https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/pauli-lecture.pdf:

> In the autumn of 1924 I published some arguments against this point of view, which I definitely rejected as incorrect and proposed instead of it the assumption of a new quantum theoretic property of the electron, which I called a « two-valuedness not describable classically »3.

However, the reference 3 is to a paper published in January 1925.

**Reference**
W. Pauli, Z. Physik, 31 (1925) 765